# Find the eigenvalues of an unsymmetrical matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

> Eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}4 & -5 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1\ \\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$

I usually set $0$ equal to $\det(A- \lambda I)$ to find the eigenvalues, but the book says they are $2, 1$ and $0$, which isn't what I got. Am I missing a step?

Comment: [Should be](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+{{4%2C-5%2C1}%2C{1%2C0%2C-1}%2C{0%2C1%2C-1}}).

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: I get 4, 1, and -1. I just changed the matrix into the same one, but with $lambda$ subtracted from the diagonal 4, 0, and -1.

Answer (score 3):

I will take the determinant by cofactor expansion about the first column:

$$p(\lambda) = \det\begin{pmatrix} 4 - \lambda & -5 & 1 \\ 1 & -\lambda & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 - \lambda\end{pmatrix}$$

$$= (4 - \lambda)((-\lambda)(-1 - \lambda) + 1) - (-5(-1 - \lambda) - 1)$$

$$= (4 - \lambda)(\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1) - 5\lambda - 4$$

$$= -\lambda^3 + 3\lambda^2 - 2\lambda$$

$$= -\lambda(\lambda^2 - 3\lambda + 2)$$

$$= -\lambda(\lambda - 2)(\lambda - 1)$$

Now if the characteristic polynomial is set equal to zero, we get $\lambda = 0,1,2$.

Comment: Ohh ok. I had tried that approach earlier but messed up somewhere calculating the determinant. Thanks!